# Display YouTube page inside iframe

Tags: iframe, youtube, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

I want to display YouTube page inside iframe.

But it gives me an error `Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

[image]

Any idea on how to display this page inside iframe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to embed the video? `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MhkGQAoc7bc" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Youtube will not allow you to use their page on an iframe. You need to embed their videos.

Comment: i don't want to display just video but the entire youtube page like the image i attached